# `psql` command to view all existing tablespaces?

Tags: postgresql, psql, tablespace

What's the `psql` command to view all existing tablespaces?

`\l+` displays all existing databases with their configured tablespace, but it won't display tablespaces which have been created but don't yet contain a database.

Comment: Tablespaces don't "contain databases". They contain tables

Comment: Ah right, so when you `CREATE DATABASE db1 TABLESPACE tp1;`, the only purpose this serves is to configure the default tablespace for any table or index created in the database?

Comment: That's correct, yes.

Comment: `\?` to get help for backslash commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), the command to list tablespaces is `\db`

If you are looking for a command, just enter `\?` in the psql command line and it will show you all available commands including a short description.

Answer (score 6):

PSQL meta-command

```
\db+
```

SQL

```
SELECT * FROM pg_tablespace;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the psql command that you can use:

```
postgres=# \db+
                                      List of tablespaces
        Name    |  Owner   | Location | Access privileges | Options |  Size  | Description 
    ------------+----------+----------+-------------------+---------+--------+-------------
     pg_default | postgres |          |                   |         | 448 MB | 
     pg_global  | postgres |          |                   |         | 631 kB | 
    (2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to view all existing tablespaces as well as the location of non default [tablespace](https://orahow.com/check-tablespace-location-in-postgresql/) using psql.

```
postgres=# select spcname ,pg_tablespace_location(oid) from pg_tablespace;

spcname   |      pg_tablespace_location
-------------+----------------------------------
pg_default  |
pg_global   |
devdefault  | /pgdata/devdata_tbs/devdefault
temp        | /pgdata/devdata_tbs/temporary
```